# Strange behavior of the effects command of mlogit in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, non-linear-regression, mlogit

I am estimating a multionomial logit model and would like to report marginal effect. I am running into a difficulty, as when I am using a larger version of the model I get an error.

Here is an reproducible example. The following code, with two covariates, works fine.

```
library(mlogit)

df = data.frame(c(0,1,1,2,0,1,0), c(1,6,7,4,2,2,1), c(683,276,756,487,776,100,982))
colnames(df) <- c('y', 'col1', 'col3')
df$col2<-df$col1^2
mydata = df

mldata <- mlogit.data(mydata, choice="y", shape="wide")
mlogit.model1 <- mlogit(y ~ 1| col1+col2, data=mldata)
m <- mlogit(y ~ 1| col1+col2, data = mldata)
z <- with(mldata, data.frame(col1 = tapply(col1, index(m)$alt, mean), 
                             col2 = tapply(col2, index(m)$alt, mean) ) )
effects(mlogit.model1, covariate = "col1", data = z)
```

Now, when I have three covariates:

```
mlogit.model1 <- mlogit(y ~ 1| col1+col2+col3, data=mldata)
m <- mlogit(y ~ 1| col1+col2+col3, data = mldata)
z <- with(mldata, data.frame(col1 = tapply(col1, index(m)$alt, mean), 
                             col2 = tapply(col2, index(m)$alt, mean), 
                             col3 = tapply(col3, index(m)$alt, mean) ) )
effects(mlogit.model1, covariate = "col1", data = z)
```

The last line gives the following error:

> Error in if (rhs %in% c(1, 3)) { : argument is of length zero

But if I run

```
effects(mlogit.model1, covariate = "col3", data = z)
```

then it works ok for giving the marginal effects of `col3`. Why would it not give the marginal effects of `col1`?

Note that all columns contain no `NULL`s and are of the same length. Can someone explain what's the reason for this behavior?

Comment: This means that `rhs` is an empty vector. You will probably have to make this reproducible to get a full answer. One small step toward reproducibility is noting which line produces the error.

Comment: It is the last line, I did mention it in the question (at the end)

Comment: One possibility is to dig around in the `effects` function (if is isn't compiled) to see what "rhs" refers to. Then you might be able to back track to why it is empty.

Comment: a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of getting an answer (someone else might be willing to do the digging in `effects` for you, but if you don't give a reproducible example they will have to make up their own reproducible example, which will be a lot harder and maybe not worth it)

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker! Added reproducible example.

Comment: @splinter - did the pointer and code address your issue? I believe it does - just checking if I missed anything.

Comment: Thank you kindly @Technophobe01, I cannot check it yet because I away on another computer, but will get the change in the next several days.

Comment: @splinter - No worries - happy to help. Scotland a find locale. Check out Glen Coe - I miss the scenery :-)

Comment: Thanks @Technophobe01, Glen Coe is very nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My sense is this may help guide you to a solution.

Reference: http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/44314-calculate-marginal-effects-using-mlogit-package

```
> methods(effects)
[1] effects.glm*    effects.lm*     effects.mlogit*
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code 
Note: Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

Explanation:

A little transformation in the source code of effects.mlogit is required.

In line 16 you should replace "cov.list <- lapply(attr(formula(object), "rhs"), as.character)" with "cov.list <- strsplit(as.character(attr(formula(object), "rhs")), " + ", fixed = TRUE)"

Fix Result:

```
> effects(mlogit.model1, covariate = "col1", data = z)
            0             1             2 
-4.135459e-01  4.135459e-01  9.958986e-12 

> myeffects(mlogit.model2, covariate = "col1", data = z2)
           0            1            2 
 1.156729129 -1.157014778  0.000285649
```

### Code

```
require(mlogit)

myeffects<-function (object, covariate = NULL, type = c("aa", "ar", "rr", 
                                                        "ra"), data = NULL, ...) 
{
  type <- match.arg(type)
  if (is.null(data)) {
    P <- predict(object, returnData = TRUE)
    data <- attr(P, "data")
    attr(P, "data") <- NULL
  }
  else P <- predict(object, data)
  newdata <- data
  J <- length(P)
  alt.levels <- names(P)
  pVar <- substr(type, 1, 1)
  xVar <- substr(type, 2, 2)
  cov.list <- strsplit(as.character(attr(formula(object), "rhs")), " + ", fixed = TRUE)
  rhs <- sapply(cov.list, function(x) length(na.omit(match(x, 
                                                           covariate))) > 0)
  rhs <- (1:length(cov.list))[rhs]
  eps <- 1e-05
  if (rhs %in% c(1, 3)) {
    if (rhs == 3) {
      theCoef <- paste(alt.levels, covariate, sep = ":")
      theCoef <- coef(object)[theCoef]
    }
    else theCoef <- coef(object)[covariate]
    me <- c()
    for (l in 1:J) {
      newdata[l, covariate] <- data[l, covariate] + eps
      newP <- predict(object, newdata)
      me <- rbind(me, (newP - P)/eps)
      newdata <- data
    }
    if (pVar == "r") 
      me <- t(t(me)/P)
    if (xVar == "r") 
      me <- me * matrix(rep(data[[covariate]], J), J)
    dimnames(me) <- list(alt.levels, alt.levels)
  }
  if (rhs == 2) {
    newdata[, covariate] <- data[, covariate] + eps
    newP <- predict(object, newdata)
    me <- (newP - P)/eps
    if (pVar == "r") 
      me <- me/P
    if (xVar == "r") 
      me <- me * data[[covariate]]
    names(me) <- alt.levels
  }
  me
}

df = data.frame(c(0,1,1,2,0,1,0), c(1,6,7,4,2,2,1), c(683,276,756,487,776,100,982))
colnames(df) <- c('y', 'col1', 'col3')
df$col2<-df$col1^2
mydata = df

mldata <- mlogit.data(mydata, choice="y", shape="wide")
mlogit.model1 <- mlogit(y ~ 1| col1+col2, data=mldata)
m <- mlogit(y ~ 1| col1+col2, data = mldata)
z <- with(mldata, data.frame(col1 = tapply(col1, index(m)$alt, mean), 
                             col2 = tapply(col2, index(m)$alt, mean) ) )

mldata2 <- mlogit.data(mydata, choice="y", shape="wide")
mlogit.model2 <- mlogit(y ~ 1| col1+col2+col3, data=mldata2)
m2 <- mlogit(y ~ 1| col1+col2+col3, data = mldata2)
z2 <- with(mldata, data.frame(col1 = tapply(col1, index(m2)$alt, mean), 
                             col2 = tapply(col2, index(m2)$alt, mean), 
                             col3 = tapply(col3, index(m2)$alt, mean) ) )

effects(mlogit.model1, covariate = "col1", data = z)
myeffects(mlogit.model2, covariate = "col1", data = z2)
```